# Calling variable of another function to outside function

Tags: python

how can I call a variable value of a function, to another function.

```
def a1():
    global ant
    ant = 3

def a2():
    c = 5
    c = 5 + ant
a2()
```

How can I call the variable ant inside the function `a2`? I don't want to use return.
I get this error NameError: name 'ant' is not defined, when I call a2()

Comment: exactly the way you did. what you wrote did not work ???

Comment: global variables are an anti-pattern in most cases. `return` should be preffered

Comment: *"I don't want to use return."* Use it anyway. There's no reason not to use `return`, but a million reasons to avoid global variables.

Comment: I get this error NameError: name 'ant' is not defined

Comment: @Tolu  Check the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `ant` outside the function and `globalize` it inside it.

```
ant = 0
def a1():
     global ant
     ant = 3

def a2():
    c = 5
    c = 5 + ant
    print(c)

a1()
a2()
```

OUTPUT:

```
8
```

> Note: It is indeed better to use return than global.

Using `return`:

```
def a1():
     ant = 3
     return ant

def a2(ant_val):
    c=5
    c=5+ant_val
    print(c)

ant_val = a1()
a2(ant_val)
```

OUTPUT:

```
8
```

**EDIT:**

OP: *I get this error* `NameError: name 'ant' is not defined`, *when I call* `a2()`

Ans: That is because it is not `defined`, call `a1()` first and then `a2()`

OR

Use the first approach in my answer and you dont have to call `a1()` first, since it is already defined:
 `ant = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def a1():
    global ant
    ant=3

def a2():     
    c=5
    c=5+ant
    print(c)

a1()
a2()
```